# list items in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to add a border between the list items , I'm following a tutorial and in the video I typed the same exact code (I didn't include all the CSS code here). The problem is there is no margin or space between the first list item and second list item. There's also an extra border after the .

```css
header li :first-child {
 border-right: 1px solid #373535;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en" >
<head>
 <title> My Recipe </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<!-- yolo this is my first project -->
</head>

<body>
    <header>
     <div class="Left">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="">Popular recipes</a> </li>
          <li><a href="">Whats New</a> </li>
        </ul> 
     </div>

     <div class="Right">
      <ul>
          <li> <a href="">Categories</a> </li>
          <li><a href="">Meal Ideas</a> </li>
        </ul> 
     </div>

     <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/chefs-hat.png"/>
        <p>My recipes</p>
     </div>
 </header>


</body>


</html>
```

The result:

[image: the result]

Comment: Kudo's for the `<!-- yolo this is my first project -->`

Answer (score 1):

Try this css

```
header li *:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #373535;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fbLnwbr1/)

css

```
ul {
  list-style:none; /* will remove bullets and the space before the list will be gone as no bullet*/
}

li {
  border-right:1px solid #000; /* add border as you like */
  display:inline-block; /* to make it inline */
  padding:20px; /* will decide space between border and content as per box model*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the whitespace to inside the `<a>` tag ie.

```
<li><a href="">Popular recipes </a></li>
```

If you don't want the border on the second list item, then your CSS should be targeting `<ul>` not `<li>`. This will then try to target the first child of the `<ul>` tag.

```
header ul:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #373535;
}
```

Comment: it didnt change anything

Comment: Are you sure? did you remove the space that you originally had between `li` and `:first-child`?

Comment: Could you try and re-write your question, as it's not very clear what you're trying to do. By 'border' do you mean a pipe?